# Redux Dispatch Keeps Running

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
  const fetchUserCognito =async()=>{
    dispatch(setCurrentCognitoUserThunk())
  }

  const fetchUserData=async()=>{
    dispatch(getUserData(user.currentUser))
  }

  const fetchTopCategories=async()=>{
    dispatch(getTopCategoryOfUser(String(user.currentUser)))
  }
  const fetchingProcess=()=>{
    fetchUserCognito()
    .then(()=>{fetchUserData()})
    .then(()=>{fetchTopCategories()})
    .finally(()=>dispatch(closeLoader({})))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    //fetching Datas to display it
    fetchingProcess()
    orderCategories();
    dispatch(closeLoader({}))
  }, []);
```

Hi, i am trying to fetch data from my api but when I try like this redux infinitely running my dispatches, I checked the other questions yet couldn't find any problem with my code

Comment: I can see my data coming from api btw

Comment: Is something maybe unmounting and mounting your component? Maybe some routing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the current components state to keep track of whether the effect should be executed or not, i.e.

`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`

execute your function calls in the useEffect if loading is true and before executing it set it to false. That way you will have complete control of when and how your effect executes.

It is also a good idea to wrap your functions with useCallback to ensure that they do not execute every time the current component's state is updated. Don't forget to pass the proper variable dependencies to your useCallbacks.

If you follow this paradigm your code will look like the following:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const fetchUserCognito =useCallback(async()=>{
    dispatch(setCurrentCognitoUserThunk())
}, []);
    
const fetchUserData=useCallback(async()=>{
    dispatch(getUserData(user.currentUser))
}, []);
    
const fetchTopCategories=useCallback(async()=>{
  dispatch(getTopCategoryOfUser(String(user.currentUser)))
}, []);

const fetchingProcess=useCallback(()=>{
    fetchUserCognito()
    .then(()=>{fetchUserData()})
    .then(()=>{fetchTopCategories()})
    .finally(()=>dispatch(closeLoader({})))
 }, []);
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
        //fetching Datas to display it
        fetchingProcess()
        orderCategories();
        dispatch(closeLoader({}))
    }
  }, [loading]);
```

Comment: I did apply the changes that you suggest but It still running infinitely, //state.userData = userDatas,
If I comment out this line, it doesn't keep running the function

Comment: I suggest you share a little bit more of your code and how you add the fetched data to the state and then how you start rendering based on the data. I believe that's where the problem is.